# href not working in beamer (not clickable)

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I have a beamer presentation and I would like to include a beamer presentation. the label from `\href` shows on the screen, but not as a link and it is not clickable. Same thing happens with `\url`.

Reduced example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Historic data}
    \begin{itemize}
     \item Evolution over time $\rightarrow$ \href{http://drupalfun.com/dance/index.html}{Time machine}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks rather incomplete than reduced.

Comment: I elaborated a bit more, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I have to comment out the `\usetheme` to be able to compile your code. But the hyperlink is clickable and takes me to the right web address. Maybe it's the theme you're using that's causing the problem? Try switching to a different theme or investigate the theme you're using and see if the problem persists.

Comment: The problem may stem from your viewer rather than from your code. Have you tried opening the output in another viewer? Is the problem still present there?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It didn't work in ocular and acroread. Turn out I had the selection tool on instead of browsing tool in both softwares. Works now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as per @Jubob's suggestion, I looked at my viewer. It didn't work in ocular and acroread. Turns out I had the selection tool on instead of browsing tool in both softwares. Works now!

Comment: haha, nice! saved my day.